# Bind Livewire property within Blade component in Laravel 8 Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

On a fresh Laravel 8.4 installation with Jetstream, I have a (full) Livewire component which doesn't render in Blade component slot.

Route:

```
 // App/Livewire/Page/Index -> livewire full component
 Route::get('pages', Page::class)->name('page.index');
```

Liviwire component class app/livewire/Page/ `Index.php`

```
public $search = '';
public function updatingSearch() {
    $this->resetPage();
}

public function render()
{
    $pages = Page::where(function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
    })
    ->paginate(10);

    return view('livewire.page.index', [
        'pages' => $pages
    ]);
}
```

App layout (layouts/app.blade.php)

```
<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <x-jet-banner />

    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        @livewire('navigation-menu')

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        @if (isset($header))
            <header class="bg-white shadow">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    {{ $header }}
                </div>
            </header>
        @endif

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <main>
            {{ $slot }}
        </main>
    </div>

    @stack('modals')

    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Liviwire component

```
<div>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                {{ __('Dogs') }}
            </h2>
            
            <!-- This input doesn't bind to search property within the Livewire class because it's inside a named slot -->
            <input type="text" wire:model="search">
        </div>
    </x-slot>

    <!-- This input successfully binds to search as expected because it is in the default slot -->
    <input type="text" wire:model="search">
</div>
```

After some debugging, found that the livewire works as expected within the default slot of the layout, but not inside a named slot (header).

Is there any soltion to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to do this because I was under the impression that named slots were somewhat different than the main slot.  However, I found this - it may be helpful: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/livewire/livewire/2322/756962391

Comment: well, this soluition makes sense indeed and I was also thinking that it could be due to placing the content somewhere else than under the livewire controll. But since I'm using full livewire component, not very sure on which DOM node livewire starts to cover. Maybe under <main>, since the header component didn't work in my case. Anyway I've figured it out in the end by including the <header> section inside the default slot as well and now Livewire works as expected. Thanks for your reply

Comment: please don't use gitmemory.com, this is the original source: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2322